# How are connect-mongo MongoStore sessions actually saved?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I implemented sessions using **`Passport`**, but for storing sessions I tried **`connect-mongo`** using a **`mongoose`** connection.

This is my code (sessions part):

```
var express     =       require('express')
var mongodb     =       require('mongodb')
var mongoose    =       require('mongoose')
var bodyParser  =       require('body-parser')
var cookie      =       require('cookie-parser')
var connect     =       require('connect')
var passport    =       require('passport')
//var flash         =       require('connect-flash')
var session     =       require('express-session');
var MongoStore  =       require('connect-mongo')(session);
var LocalStrategy =     require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express()

var BSON = mongodb.BSONPure

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"))
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(cookie())
app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/psicologosTuxtepecDB')



var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var userCredential = new Schema({

    username:   String,
    password:   String

},  {
    collection:     'members'
})

var userCredentials = mongoose.model('members', userCredential)



app.use(session({
    secret: 'ziKologiia',
    clear_interval: 900,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    store: new MongoStore({
      db : mongoose.connection.db
    })
  }));
```

Something I doubt if it would be counterproductive is that `app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })) is using`connect  module but the MongoStore configuration is set upon a `express-session` variable. However, deleting first causes app to not work good (won't authenticate/redirect).

So, about my question title. **Where is that session stored?** I really thought I could go to my Mongo database and find any *collection* storing it.

How can I find such sessions at backend (Mongo) and even at the applicacion as Java Script objects?

Comment: Don't you have a `sessions` collection in your db?

Comment: I don't have it, wouldn't it just be created by default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`connect-mongo` stores sessions in the ["sessions" collection by default](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/bca754cc6ccded953f85ca37f647619f26b6783d/lib/connect-mongo.js#L22). They should be there and visible in the mongo shell or any GUI tool like robomongo. Yes, it is created by default. I would pass in [the mongooose_connection option](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/bca754cc6ccded953f85ca37f647619f26b6783d/lib/connect-mongo.js#L81) instead of `db`.

From the docs:

> mongoose_connection in the form: someMongooseDb.connections[0] to use an existing mongoose connection. (optional)

Comment: Could you show any example of your suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: `store: new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connections[0] })`

Comment: One more question related to the topic, how is it possible that I do `app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' }));` and then at MongoStore config have a `secret: 'ziKologiia',..`.

If I delete first, it won't work good, how can these two secrets be, *compatible*?

Comment: MongoStore doesn't take a `secret` option from what I can tell. `connect.session` does all the logic, the mongo store just provides persistent storage.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you should do is replace

```
app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' }));
```

with your

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'ziKologiia',
  clear_interval: 900,
  cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  store: new MongoStore({
    db: mongoose.connection.db
  });
}));
```

Comment: If I replace `app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' }));` it'll work wrong. Not managing sessions redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Method of MongoClient:

```
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";

app.use(
    session({
        secret: "Your Key",
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24, //1Sec * 1H * 24 = 1 Day
            secure:  process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"? false : true
        },
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
      store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MongoDBUrl}),
    })
);
```