# Where does express js save session details?

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-cookies

Like PHP stores its session details likely at the following location `/var/lib/php/session` where does `express js` store the the session details ?

Where I can manually go and check out the session variables and all?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the session store you use. By default it stores it in memory, but you can use [Redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis), [MySQL](https://github.com/nlf/connect-mysql), etc. to save sessions. There are middleware for many common stores on npm.

Comment: can you give an eye to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773537/how-are-connect-mongo-mongostore-sessions-actually-saved

Comment: @mscdex you mean, that if I don't use the DB and restart my node server, all the sessions will be lost :-o  ????

At least in PHP they are automatically persistently stored in some location

Comment: @rahulg Yes, that's why you should only use the default Store for testing purposes.